# Node.js make async calls to API in chunks

Tags: node.js

How can I make a call to an external API to keep them asynchronous?

The glitch is that I need to make couple of millions of calls, so I'd like to send  10 of them at the time and once any one of them is back, send another one, and keep doing that until all of them are complete.

So it is kind of like running 10 threads simultaneously.

Comment: Why do you want to limit to 10?

Comment: https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel

Comment: Seems like a reasonable amount. Probably 100 would be also fine. The requests have to be chunked, not to send thousands of calls at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using request.js you can also use the pool config option which limits the outstanding requests

In request.js

pool: {
    maxSockets: 10
  }

https://github.com/request/request

agent - http(s).Agent instance to use
agentClass - alternatively specify your agent's class name
agentOptions - and pass its options. Note: for HTTPS see tls API doc for TLS/SSL options and the documentation above.
forever - set to true to use the forever-agent Note: Defaults to http(s).Agent({keepAlive:true}) in node 0.12+
pool - An object describing which agents to use for the request. If this option is omitted the request will use the global agent (as long as your options allow for it). Otherwise, request will search the pool for your custom agent. If no custom agent is found, a new agent will be created and added to the pool. Note: pool is used only when the agent option is not specified.
A maxSockets property can also be provided on the pool object to set the max number of sockets for all agents created (ex: pool: {maxSockets: Infinity}).
Note that if you are sending multiple requests in a loop and creating multiple new pool objects, maxSockets will not work as intended. To work around this, either use request.defaults with your pool options or create the pool object with the maxSockets property outside of the loop.
timeout - Integer containing the number of milliseconds to wait for a server to send response headers (and start the response body) before aborting the request. Note that if the underlying TCP connection cannot be established, the OS-wide TCP connection timeout will overrule the timeout option (the default in Linux can be anywhere from 20-120 seconds).